# create row resulting in mean of column value equal under condition in R

Tags: r, row

Hei,

I would like to create a new row added to a data frame, the row will be the result of the mean of two value from same column under conditions.

Example is :
a data frame of 3 columns: Date, Depth, DIC

I would like to

when value into Date column is equal to the same value in column Date (df$Date==df$Date)
I would like to create a row in the data frame with mean into column DIC, the same value in column Date, value 100 in column Depth.

thanks for the help!!!

```
   df<-structure(list(Date = c(18381L, 18381L, 18448L, 18448L, 18395L, 
                               18395L, 18402L, 18402L, 18409L), Depth = c(50L, 150L, 50L, 150L, 
                                                                          50L, 150L, 50L, 150L, 50L), DIC= c(2157L, 2150L, 2161L, 2154L,2144L, 2152L, 2123L, 2155L, 2137L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-9L))
```

Comment: Do you want  `df %>% group_by(Date, Depth) %>% group_modify(~ add_row(.x, DIC = mean(.x$DIC)))`

Comment: @akrun yes exactly, with the new depth = 100

Answer (score 0):

We could use `add_row` after grouping by 'Date'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df %>%
   group_by(Date) %>%
   group_modify(~ add_row(.x, Depth = mean(.x$Depth), DIC = mean(.x$DIC))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 × 3
    Date Depth   DIC
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 18381    50 2157 
 2 18381   150 2150 
 3 18381   100 2154.
 4 18395    50 2144 
 5 18395   150 2152 
 6 18395   100 2148 
 7 18402    50 2123 
 8 18402   150 2155 
 9 18402   100 2139 
10 18409    50 2137 
11 18409    50 2137 
12 18448    50 2161 
13 18448   150 2154 
14 18448   100 2158.
```